# Reference the latest revision in document footer?

Tags: revision-control

I've created a revision history table in my document to track a high-level description of the various changes. The footer also lists the revision number so every page has an instant identifier of what version of the document it is.

Unfortunately, the version number in the footer is manually updated.

**Q) Is there a way to have the footer automatically reference the latest revision number?**

My footer currently says

```
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize \thepage \\ [document_name] 2.2.0 \\ \today }
```

I am using `fancyhdr`.

The revision history is currently maintained in a table and looks like this where the description of the changes of each revision is on a new line.

```
\begin{longtable}{| m{1.5cm} | m{3.5cm} | m{5.0cm} | m{8.0cm} |}
Issue No. & Issue Date & Approver & Description of changes \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
1.0.0 & [date] & [approver] &
[description of 1.0.0]
\\ \hline
1.1.0 & [date] & [approver] &
[description of 1.1.0]
\\ \hline
2.0.0 & [date] & [approver] &
[description of 2.0.0]
\\ \hline 
2.1.0 & [date] & [approver] &
[description of 2.1.0]
\\ \hline 
2.2.0 & [date] & [approver] &
[description of 2.2.0]
\\ \hline
```

I would like the footer to automatically know to reference the latest rev number (so when I create an entry for 2.2.1, 2.3.0, or 3.0.0, the footer is automatically updated as opposed to requiring me to update both the table and the footer).

I saw some posts about the `vhistory` package but I didn't see anything mentioning a capability to smartly reference an entry in the `vhistory` table. Does `vhistory` actually have that capability (and if so, how do I initiate the referencing)?

Editing to include a MWE per campa's request:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}
\title{my title}
\author{team name}
\date{\today}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize \thepage \\ document name 2.2.0 \\ \today }

\begin{center}
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{longtable}{| m{1.5cm} | m{3.5cm} | m{5.0cm} | m{8.0cm} |}
            \hline
            Issue No. & Issue Date & Approver & Description of changes \\ \hline
            \endfirsthead
            1.0.0 & [date] & [approver] &
            [description of 1.0.0]
            \\ \hline
            1.1.0 & [date] & [approver] &
            [description of 1.1.0]
            \\ \hline
            2.0.0 & [date] & [approver] &
            [description of 2.0.0]
            \\ \hline 
            2.1.0 & [date] & [approver] &
            [description of 2.1.0]
            \\ \hline 
            2.2.0 & [date] & [approver] &
            [description of 2.2.0]
            \\ \hline
        \end{longtable}
    \end{landscape}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I am looking for a way to reference the largest number in the table. Would it be easier if I reversed the direction of the rev history (i.e. put 2.2.0 at the top and display the changes in reverse chronological order)? Is there some way to smartly reference the highest number of the rev history? Would I need to change from a table to some other format (which is an option if it provides a better solution)?

Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. This makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you.

Comment: what version control are you using? I tend to use subversion and there are setups that can handle revision numbers down to the level of each file in a project (thus I have different timestamps at the bottom of my chapters)

Comment: I am using GitHub for our VCS.

Comment: Post updated with MWE per the request from @campa .